# Accident-Prone Roads: Segmentation Challenge

Tags: postgis, gdal

I am trying to analyze how many crashes happen relative to the amount of traffic on roads in California, to which end I have the following data (from Caltrans, California's DOT)

1. Roads (`LINESTRING` and `MULTILINESRING`)
   There are many segments here that are sub-segments of others. In other words, many stretches of road are double counted.
2. Traffic Counts (`MULTIPOINT`)
   One point for each direction of of traffic
3. Crashes (longitude and latitude)
   Many (~half) accidents happen in intersections, and therefore snap to several segments.

I match a crash to a roadway using logic like this:

```
ST_Distance(ST_Transform(ST_Point(-longitude, latitude), 'epsg:4326','epsg:3857'), roadway.geometry) < 20
```

I.e., the distance from the crash to the roadway is less than 20 meters. Then I use a window function to find the closest roadway.

The traffic counts are matched to the roadway in a similar fashion. So far so good.

Given a traffic count at a point (lon,lat) on a road (`LINESTRING`), how do I create a segment of that road that runs to the nearest intersection in both directions?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour], which emphasizes the importance of asking One question per Question. Please [Edit] your Question to have just one question.

Comment: @Vince: Post updated so that there is only one question.

Comment: Looking at the code, you absolutely do not want to use ST_Distance in EPSG:3857. Web Mercator is famous (infamous, really) for being inaccurate for distance. The only way to get accurate distance is to use an appropriate projection in the area of interest, or to use geodesic calculation between `geography` objects.  Also, using `ST_DIstance` for query is suboptimal -- instead use `ST_DWithin` (which can exploit a spatial index). Finally, note that point-on-line is a fraught comparison -- you should use a search distance threshold to filter nearest line.

Comment: Thank you! I guess the Linear Reference System is an alternative. Each point where traffic is counted has a postmile value.